# I don't want to use Thread.sleep() with Action class while making the method for file upload in Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am making generic method using Robot class to upload the files. But after creating the object of Robot class I've to call Thread.sleep() method. Is there any other way to add the wait as using Thread.sleep() method is not good practice.

```
public static void uploadFile(String EnterFilePath) throws AWTException {
        setClipboardData(EnterFilePath);
        Robot rb = new Robot();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        
    }
```

If I am not using Thread.sleep() method then it is not executing the sequence of actions at all.

Comment: `rb.waitForIdle();` might work.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Though Question is not clear, I will try to answer.

Your Thread.sleep() is for a reason. My best guess is its waiting for Page to Load. Your DOM should be ready to fire the actions. Rather than using Random Thread.sleep() in any Methods. Use below in driver initialization.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The above code will wait up to 10 seconds for page loading. If the page loading exceeds the time it will throw the TimeoutException.

Comment: I'm already using Implicit wait before calling this method in my testcase. So, this is not working.